# How to simplify identical method call

Tags: apache-pig

Hi I have the following Pig code:

```
leafNodes = FOREACH records GENERATE
  'buckets' AS bucket_url,
  MultiConcat(localziedName, ' in ', localizedLocation) AS title,
  ToJSONString(
      'url', url,
      'title', MultiConcat(localziedName, ' in ', localizedLocation)
  ) AS link_json;
```

The same `MultiConcat(localziedName, ' in ', localizedLocation)` call is made twice. So, is there a way to use variable or something like that to reduce the call to once?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the second call with title?

Comment: Yes, I did. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it. Basically, just create a variable right before the GENERATE statement. Here is the code:

```
leafNodes = FOREACH records {
  title = MultiConcat(localziedName, ' in ', localizedLocation);
  GENERATE
  'buckets' AS bucket_url,
  title,
  ToJSONString(
      'url', url,
      'title', title
  ) AS link_json;
}
```